# How many sets correspond to connected graphs

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, project-euler

I'm trying to solve [this](https://projecteuler.net/problem=553) project euler problem.  I don't want to get too much help, since that would defeat the purpose, but I'm hitting a wall, so I'm asking a related problem here, from which I'll hopefully be able to work toward a solution.  Let $X \subseteq (\mathcal P(\{1,\ldots,n\})-\emptyset)
$ such that every element of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ is a member of at least one element of $X$, that is $\bigcup_{s \in X} s = \{1,\ldots,n\}
$. Let $G(X)$ be the graph whose vertices are elements of $X$ and whose edges connect vertices with non-empty intersections.  I'm looking for some way to calculate the number of possible $X$ such that $G(X)$ is connected, or failing that some insight into how else I might approach the problem.

Comment: Clarification: $X$ is a nonempty collection of the nonempty subsets of $\{1,2,\dots, n\}$ (with this other property)?

Comment: Yes, assuming by collection you mean set.  There are two other properties shared by the $X$'s we want to count, by the way.  One being that every element of $\{1,2,...,n\}$ appears in at least one element of $X$, and the other being that $G(X)$ is connected.

Comment: Then I don't understand the edge structure. Suppose that (omitting inner braces for readability) $X=\{1,2,12\}$; where are the edges in $G(X)$?

Comment: there is an edge from $12$ to each of $1$ and $2$ but not between $1$ and $2$.  Basically, there is an edge between two subsets of $P(n)$ if they have at least one element in common.

Comment: @Servaes: No. A trivial example is $X=\{\{1\},\cdots,\{n\}\}$. This idea leads to a lot of examples, like $X=\{1,12,23,4,45\}$ (inner braces omitted).

Answer (score 1):

NB This isn't a full answer, but it gives an alternative perspective which may be useful.

I find it a bit easier to follow with fewer levels of indirection:
$$X \subseteq (\mathcal P(\{1,\ldots,n\})-\emptyset)$$
with the additional constraint $$\bigcup_{s \in X} s = \{1,\ldots,n\}$$

Consider the graph $H$ whose vertices are $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ and whose edges form all two-element subsets of the elements of $X$. In other words, every set $s \in X$ is a clique in $H$. If two elements $s_1, s_2 \in X$ have an element in common, all of the elements of $s_1 \cup s_2$ are in the same connected component of $H$. Therefore $H$ has exactly as many connected components as $G$.

For any given $H$, the cliques form an upper bound on $X$. The question of which subsets of the cliques are strictly necessary to generate $H$ is not obviously trivial. However, since your question asks about the case where $G$ (and hence $H$) is connected: each spanning tree corresponds to an $X$ consisting of $n-1$ two-element sets; and each $X$ which gives a connected $G$ can be extended by adding new sets or by adding elements to the existing sets. An inclusion-exclusion calculation might be feasible.

Comment: I'm still digesting your answer, but I definitely agree with your point about indirection.  Your formulation is much clearer.  I'll update the question statement accordingly.

Comment: Actually, thinking about it, inclusion-exclusion is back to front. The solution lies instead in a recursion which lets you calculate the number of $X$ for $n$ elements which correspond to connected graphs given the numbers of sets of $1,\ldots,n-1$ elements which correspond to connected graphs. I don't think I can say any more without giving the whole game away.

Comment: Peter, I think I also arrived at the idea in your comment, but I wonder if you have a nicer solution in mind. In particular, I can write mine as a (double) sum with n*stirling_2(n,k) terms; are you looking at a more compact form? Also, @GabrielBurns: are you okay with a full solution to this problem? (since it's not the the one asked by PE).

Comment: @Eric Stucky Yes, I would be.  I think there's still enough to do on the PE problem after this is solved.

Comment: @EricStucky, that sounds like the same one, although I haven't actually written down the full details. I personally (as an erstwhile PE user) don't think I could give the solution without also giving away more of the PE problem than I would want to, leaving only a small mechanical step.